# Django python regex to include dollar symbol in URL

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a Django 1.5 app wherein a particular URL is used to generate code 128 barcodes. I have a regular expression written for this URL which is as follows

```
...
url(r'^code/(?P<barcode>[.a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$', CreateBarcode.as_view(), name='create_barcode'),
...
```

This works fine for generating barcodes for values such as

```
www.xyz.com/code/123ABC456/
www.xyz.com/code/AAA-BBBB-CCC/
www.xyz.com/code/A_B_C/
```

I recently had a problem where I had to generate a barcode for a value which contains a dollar symbol `$` in it. I have tried out the below regular expressions but to no success

```
url(r'^code/(?P<code>[$.a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$', ....),
url(r'^code/(?P<code>[\$.a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$', ....),
url(r'^code/(?P<code>[.a-zA-Z0-9_-][$]+)/$', ....),
url(r'^code/(?P<code>[.a-zA-Z0-9_-\$]+)/$', ....),
```

All of these return a 404 response since the URL patterns could not be matched. Let me know if there is any way of getting this implemented?

Comment: ```[\$.a-zA-Z0-9_-]``` this sould work..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) module to solve your problem, instead of using regex pattern.

```
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('code/<str:barcode>/', CreateBarcode.as_view(), name='create_barcode'),
]
```

> `path` module only support for `django>=2.0`

Answer (score 0):

The second regex pattern I had mentioned actually worked. The issue was that the server did not pick up the changes when I updated the code.

```
url(r'^code/(?P<code>[\$.a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$', ....),
```

Thanks @binpy and @Sumithran